# How to develop an excel add in that executes macro?

Tags: .net, excel, vba

I would like to develop a simple Excel add in that executes VBA macros. 
I would like to add a button / dropdown list in Excel ... Our company Excel's are etherogenous: Excel 2003 to Excel 2010.
How to do this ? Which documentation to see ? 
One note: i can develop in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at NetOffice http://netoffice.codeplex.com/
It will be in .NET and the latest version of Add-In are compatible with Office 2007+, since they change the Add-In implementation on older versions.
http://netoffice.codeplex.com/documentation for the documentation. You'll find some basic examples how to run it. You will have to check COM files, it's some work behind. In case you get stuck, ask SebastianDotNet on the website, he's developper of the NetOffice. To download the libraries here http://netoffice.codeplex.com/releases/view/70943 and select the .NET version of your project. See you soon on the forum there.

Answer (score 0):

Under the developer tab in excel you can insert certain controls including buttons and drop down menus that will run whatever macro you tell them to run.

If that is not good enough for you, then go here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm and you will find that good sir Ron de Bruin explains very well how to change the ribbon such that you can create your own menu of buttons that run different macros.

In this way, no add in is needed at all!